# Scala array ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: string, scala, split

I have this Scala code:

```
val line = "DB:move"
val str = line.split(":")       
println(line.split(':')(1))
```

When the index is one `1` get

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

but when I put the index as `0` no issues at all.

Comment: can you print your line ?

Comment: You got to be kidding me. That line split can't generate that error !

Comment: Works fine for me: ```val line = "DB:move"
val str = line.split(":")
println(line.split(':')(1))

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

move
line: String = DB:move
str: Array[String] = Array(DB, move)```

Answer (score 0):

When you split a string on a character/string that is not in that string you'll get back an array that contains single element - the initial string:

```
scala> "asdf".split(":")
res0: Array[String] = Array(asdf)
```

Arrays are 0 based, so accessing first element at index 0 is fine, but throws for index 1.